# Get post title from ACF - select post

Tags: wordpress, field, advanced-custom-fields

I have beginner with ACF and WordPress as developer. 
So, I want to select which title post has to be displayed in div from WordPress panel. I have got some ACF file called "hot_news" which is post object. Returned content is post object, not ID.

I have got also "Show if post is equal to (some post title)".

This is my code:

```
<div class="bp1-col-1-1 news-line">
    <a class="button button-hot-news" href="#">Aktualności</a>
    <img class="hot-icon hot-icon-left" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/warning-icon.png" alt="Hot news!">
    <div class="morquee-efect">
        <a class="hot-news-title" href="#"><?php the_field('hot_news'); ?></a>
    </div>
    <img class="hot-icon hot-icon-right" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/warning-icon.png" alt="Hot news!">
</div>
```

When I make  it is displayed, but  does not display post title. What is wrong?

Comment: where you are printing title?

Comment: @MujeebuRahman here:
<a class="hot-news-title" href="#"><?php the_field('hot_news'); ?></a>

Answer (score 0):

to retrieve a field from ACF you should use **get_field** so

```
  <?php echo get_field('hot_news'); ?>
```

prints the current post custom field named "hot_news".

If you want you can specify a post ID :

```
<?php echo get_field('hot_news'[,post_ID]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You said in your question that `hot_news` is a post object. Therefore, if you try to echo an object, you're not going to get what you want.

Instead, you'll have to do something like:

```
<div class="bp1-col-1-1 news-line">
    <a class="button button-hot-news" href="#">Aktualności</a>
    <img class="hot-icon hot-icon-left" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/warning-icon.png" alt="Hot news!">
    <div class="morquee-efect">
        <a class="hot-news-title" href="#"><?php
          $hotnews = get_field('hot_news');
          if($hotnews) echo $hotnews->post_title;
        ?></a>
    </div>
    <img class="hot-icon hot-icon-right" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/warning-icon.png" alt="Hot news!">
</div>
```

You can get more info on how to work with an ACF post object here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/

My method should work if you just need the simple post title, but if you start needing permalinks to the post and stuff like that, it may make sense to use the `setup_postdata($post)` code that the ACF docs use.

Comment: Ehh, does not work. Could you add it to my code and show me this to be sure that I applied this well?

Comment: Can you provide a little more information about what's not working? Is there any link shown? Try running var_dump($hotnews) and pasting the output here.

Comment: var_dump($hotnews) gives "NULL"

Comment: Ok, then the hot_news field isn't being stored or accessed properly. In ACF's admin screen, is the hot_news field attached to a specific post, or is it in an Options panel? Basically, where are you setting the value of hot_news in the wp-admin area?